# How to edit/compile ROS source code

Tags: compile, catkin, ros-comm, source, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon,

I am trying to encrypt ros logs for a project, I currently have jade installed and running on an ubuntu OS. I believe the files I need to edit are in the ros_comm packages (rosconsole and rosout cpp files) that I found on the ROS Core Stack Github page.My biggest hurdle right now that I am facing is that I am having difficulty setting up my environment that would let me compile the source code. If you know of any tutorials or information that would give me an idea of how to edit and compile sections of the source code it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

Tyler

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257212/how-to-edit/compile-ros-source-code/) by [corcorant](https://answers.ros.org/users/29721/corcorant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2017-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tutorial tells you how to build as much or as little of ros as you want:

http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source

Basically, all the instructions are the same, except you can adjust the `rosinstall_generator` commands to select different packages to get. I'd recommend checking out the `-h` of `rosinstall_generator` because it has lots of options to control where you get the source from (a released version like x.y.z from a tar file vs. the "default" branch from git) and what packages you get.

Also, it's worth noting that you can build packages from source when their dependencies are installed as binaries (see the `--exclude RPP` option in `rosinstall_generator`) but any packages you want to use on top of your custom built things will also need to be from source. For example, you cannot build `ros_comm` from source and the run `rviz` from binaries and ensure that it is using your version of `ros_comm`. Instead you need to build `rviz` (and the dependencies between `rviz` and `ros_comm`) from source too.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1